# node.js POST callbacks not received

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, postman

I am POSTing a json file to a node.js listener, and I must not fully understand how POSTs are properly constructed, because in the code below the `on('data')` callback is never invoked.  I can see the actual json string in the body, so I can work around the lack of a callback, but it seems like I'm doing something wrong with how I generate my POST request. [Postman details further below]

```js
// Server initialization
var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(CookieParser.parse);
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

// Later, at the point where I register callbacks.
this.server.post('receive', function (request, respond) {
        console.log('Received POST');
        console.log("Headers: %s", JSON.stringify(request.headers));
        console.log("Body: %s", JSON.stringify(request.body));
        var body = '' ;
        var filePath = './data/notes.json';
        
        // this event is never triggered.
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('Data received.');
            body += data;
        });
        
        request.on('end', function () {
          console.log('End of POST');
          fs.writeFile(filePath, body, function () {
              respond.end();
          });                      
        });
    });
```

POST details:
I'm using Postman to create a POST request, Content-Type: application/json and the putting the json string in the raw body.  What will normally trigger the 'data' event in a POST request?  If I ignore data events and just read from the request body, will I run into issues?

[image: Payload details]

Comment: What is `this.server` I don't think the object returned by `http.createServer` has a `post` method. Are you using `express`?

Comment: I'm using restify. I'll add this to the code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `restify.bodyParser`, that middleware would have already read the request body so there isn't any more for your handler to read (hence no `data` events). A stream, like `request`, can only be read once, until it's exhausted. You can't "re-read" it.

Which also means that you can just use `request.body`, which should be the (parsed) result of the JSON that you're posting.

As an aside: I don't know Postman very well, but it looks like you're sending a JSON-encoded string to the server, as opposed to a JSON-encoded *object*.

To send the latter, I would expect that this should be the raw body data:

```
{"body":"this is a test"}
```

Comment: I'm using Restify, but I suspect your answer applies in either case.

Comment: @RobertSim yeah I just checked with Restify, it behaves similarly :) I'll update my answer.